# Should I delete my comments if I've turned them into an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

If I make some comments on a question that guide the OP towards an answer, and then post an answer which is basically a copy-paste collage of my own comments, should I then delete the comments? I suppose they become redundant once the answer is posted, and I don't know if they serve much of a purpose anymore.

Comment: THat's what I'd do.

Comment: As the comments no longer serve any purpose, yes, you should definitely remove them. If appropriate, you might ask for a general comment-cleanup, or flag only obsolete comments for removal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As suggested in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267712/turning-own-comment-into-answer#comment72366_267712), if your comments don't add any value that hasn't already been added by your answer, then feel free to delete them.

It is not a requirement that you do so, but it is helpful. If you decide to do nothing, then some other users may flag your comments or the comments on the entire post for cleanup, if they're no longer useful. However, this does not reflect negatively on you.

In fact, most of the veteran users here would cleanup their own obsolete comments, since such comments only serve as a distraction from the primary content of this question and answer site: questions and answers.

Comment: It takes some cooperation, though. If I make a comment eligible for deletion, I might first *comment* on that, await the OP's move, then delete mine. Haphazardly removing your own comments may lead to a disjoint discussion. Would it be okay to flag an entire conversation as "obsolete" -- is the purpose of this obvious to the moderators?

Comment: @Jongware if you feel that a group of comments between multiple users are all obsolete, or otherwise not needed, then it is OK to just flag the entire post using the "Other" option, and explain to a moderator why the comments should be cleaned up.